# Use a variable/array from one java class, in another. Combine simple java files?

Tags: java, class, variables

Before I begin, let me apologize for my rudimentary understanding of Java, as i'm nearly sure this would be a simple problem for most any programmer.

Basically I have two Java files: The first lists all the text files in a specified directory, the second reads a specified text file and prints it out.

I am trying to figure out how to use the output of ListFiles (shown below- gives all txt files in dir) - which I assume is the variable "files" at the bottom System.out.println - and then pass it to the java file "FileData" (2nd example below) to effectively read all the txt files in a certain directory.

Maybe it would be somehow easier to make a new java file that uses the both of these? Any direction would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListFiles 
{

// bad attempt at OOP lol, f goes nowhere
public ListFiles(String f) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

  // Directory path here
  String path = "C:/WORKING_DIR_WITH_TXT_FILE"; 

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
       if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
       {
          System.out.println(files);
       }
     }
  }
}
}
```

And heres the second java file that reads a TXT file

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileData
{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {

   String file_name = "C:/WORKING_DIR_WITH_TXT_FILE";
     // "C:/directory/*.txt"???;

   try {
     ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
     String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

     int i;
     for (i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
     }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Dave's answer below is correct, but actually this is more of a fundamental piece of Object Oriented Programming (and other styles). I would suggest a beginners guide along the lines of http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/ to start with

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can currently run these two classes successfully as separate programs, but you want to invoke `ListFiles` as your main program and have it invoke `FileData` to print out the contents of the files.

In real Java applications, most classes do not have a `main` method, because they are not intended to be invoked directly from the command-line by the user.  In your case, `ListFiles` should have a `main` method so you can run it, but `FileData` should have a method that can be called from `ListFiles`.

Basically, you could change the signature of `FileData.main()` to:

```
public static void showFile(String file_name)
```

and its body would remain the same.

Then, in `ListFiles`, where you currently display the filename, you would instead/additionally have:

```
FileList.showFile( files );
```

This will invoke the method in `FileList`, passing the filename to it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Dave, and Guru, for your input, this clears things right up, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **serialize** the "files" object in the ListFiles program and **deserialize** in `FileData` class.

EDIT: As per Dave Costa's comment if You are not aware of serialize and de-serialization then
the alternative is :

Change the main method in the ListFiles to say `getListOfFiles()`.

And access it in the `FileData` class to get the list of files as `ListFiles.getListOfFiles()`.

Comment: That would be a possible approach for making two programs communicate, but I think this questioner simply doesn't understand how to make multiple classes work together in a single program.  Given his/her admitted rudimentary understanding of Java, simply saying "serialize and deserialize" doesn't seem very helpful.